# C# General method execution order

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

If some methods are called that have no other calls within them but perhaps take a long time to complete, does the order of execution remain the same as called? For example...

```
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Method1();
        Method2();        
    }
    static void Method1()
    {
        // Perhaps has many calculations that take a long time to complete
    }
    static void Method2()
    {            
    }
```

So would method 2 ever run before method 1 is finished? What could make 2 run before 1 has finished? Thanks

Comment: Method2 will only run after Method1 is finished because you have a single thread. You might want to read about threads.

Comment: There's nothing in this code that would cause any sort of threading or asynchronous operation.  Code executes in the order in which it's evaluated.

Comment: I'll dupe @YacoubMassad comment: `Method2` will only run **after** `Method1` is finished. Read about [threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).